# Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor).

Tags: reactjs

Another react question: im getting the following warning:
`Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to componentWillMount.`

```
nameFormatter: function(id, name) {
        if (this.state.editIpsetEnabled && this.state.editIpsetId === id) {
            this.setState({'newIpsetName': name});
            return (
                <input type="text"
                    value={name}
                    name="ipsetName"
                    maxLength="50"
                    className="newIpsetName"
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
            );
        } else {
            return name;
        }
}

render: function() {
    const tableData = [];
    this.state.data.map(row => {
            tableData.push(
                <tr key={row.id + row.name}>
                    <td className="col-lg-1 text-center">
                        {row.id}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-3 text-center">
                        {this.nameFormatter(row.id, row.name)}</td>
            );
        });

    return(
    .........
    {tableData}
    .........
    )
}
```

When I click `<Button onClick={() => this.editIpset(id)}>Edit</Button>` that warning shows up. When I click that button it should set `this.stateIpsetName` to `name` but it slows down and throws a bunch of warnings. How could i solve it ?

Comment: The error says `setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render...`. Your `render` function is calling `nameFormatter`, which in in turn calling `setState`. Don't do that.

Comment: To build on what @Hamms is saying, you're setting state in render which calls render... which sets state, which calls render... which is infinite recursion.

Comment: @Hamms is there way to not call render when do setState ?

Comment: @ssss no, setState will by definition trigger a rerender; you need to rethink your workflow to make sure that `setStates` are only called by user-triggered events, not by lifecycle events